# how to imitate the button in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I want to imitate the Button in QML, but why does it only work with `containsMouse` and `!containsMouse`, it doesn't work with `OnPressed`. can you help me ? Thank you.

```
   Item {
        id: area
        property string str_noPressed;
        property string str_hover;
        property string str_pressed;

        Image {
            id: background
            width: 75; height: 75
            source: userArea.containsMouse ? str_hover : str_noPressed

            MouseArea {
                id: userArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {}
                onPressed: background.source = str_pressed
                hoverEnabled: true
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, in the button is pressed, it also contains the mouse.

I assume `containsMouse` takes precedence over `onPressed`. Try:

```
onContainsMouseChanged:  {
    if (containsMouse && !pressed) {
        background.source = str_pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for help firstly.. And I am sorry. there is a wrong : Invalid property assignment: "containsMouse" is a read-only property.. It's my fault in my Code. i updated it. Then ?